# Angularjs Typeahead Performance too slow

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-typeahead

I have a list with like 1000 fields and i want to make it autocomplete, but performance seems to be to slow.
Is possible to use typeahead with big lists? This is an example code:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selectedState" typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:15" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Performance issues can be caused by a lot of reasons. I suggest you using batarang first.

Comment: i found that the problem was the ui.unique feature